# Windows 10: How to know maximum capacity of RAM of a laptop? By program/command

Tags: windows-10, command-line, memory, asus-laptop

In Linux is possible use the `dmidecode` command to know the max capacity of RAM that a Laptop/PC can support. Furthermore it shows each slot with each stick inserted with their respective values.

I have an ASUS `UX501VW-DS71T`, currently with 16GB of RAM. I want to know if is possible do an upgrade to 32GB with the exact details requested by the MOBO.

In Windows 10 how is possible accomplish the same goal? It through either a software or command

**Note** This laptop's specs or details are not listed on the ASUS web page.

Comment: Go to https://www.crucial.com/ and use their system scanner or advisor tool.

Comment: You don’t need to know the specifications posted by ASUS only the processor. What processor do you have?

Comment: Software will only tell you what the processor may theoretically support, it doesn't tell you whether the manufacturer wired it up properly to support it all to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the 2 links shared... I hope that the `wmic` command can indicate if the PC/Laptop has RAM soldered or not too.